# Android studio jump to android gradle tools source code

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Like the picture below, How can I jump to the Android Gradle plugin souce code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the source code.

---

For example：

1. open gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
2. change "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-bin.zip" to "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip"
3. sync now